# How to change the favicon dynamically in nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I want to change the favicon.ico of my project dynamically. Basically I try to change the icon based on dark or light browser theme.

Found the vueuse composable [useFavicon](https://vueuse.org/core/useFavicon/) and tried this:

```
const setFavicon = () => {
  const isDark = usePreferredDark()
  const favicon = computed(() => isDark.value ? '/img/favicon_light_png': '/img/favicon_dark.png')
  useFavicon(favicon)
}

onMounted(() => {
  setFavicon()
})
```

But there is nothing happening. Tried reloading with cache disabled and removing the default favicon.ico from public folder but no success.

Answer (score 0):

After trying for a few hours I came up with the following solution.
Maybe someone will need this in the future.

Add a 'default' favicon in your nuxt config

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
       app: {
            head: {
                   link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/png', href: "/img/favicon_light.png" }]
                }
           }
})
```

This now can be changed with the useFavicon composable. Important is that you add `{ rel: 'icon' }` as an option object to useFavicon()

```
const setFavicon = () => {
  const isDark = usePreferredDark()
  const favicon = computed(() => isDark.value ? '/img/favicon_light_png': '/img/favicon_dark.png')
  
useFavicon(favicon, {
    rel: 'icon'
  })
}
onMounted(() => {
  setFavicon()
})
```